# Can't get passed `Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying `

Tags: docker, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-cloud-run, clamav

I'm a beginner in docker and clamav. Sorry in advance if anything doesn't make sense the way I describe it.

I've got a docker image built using Maven and the Docker container toolchain and pushed the image to the Google Artifact Registry. It is then deployed to the gcloud run. It's purpose is to use the clamav virus scanner for files uploaded into an "uploaded-files" bucket. When I run the docker image locally my logs end up to look like this

```
Testing database: '/var/lib/clamav/tmp.ea3d86d12f/clamav-2a387e979c4310f2be4f06188176705f.tmp-daily.cld' ...
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (55/1800) ...Database test passed.
daily.cld updated (version: 26940, sigs: 2037113, f-level: 90, builder: raynman)
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (56/1800) ...main.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 62, sigs: 6647427, f-level: 90, builder: sigmgr)
bytecode.cvd database is up-to-date (version: 334, sigs: 91, f-level: 90, builder: anvilleg)
WARNING: Clamd was NOT notified: Can't connect to clamd through /tmp/clamd.sock: No such file or directory
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (99/1800) ...Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: Global time limit set to 120000 milliseconds.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: Global size limit set to 419430400 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: File size limit set to 104857600 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: Recursion level limit set to 17.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: Files limit set to 10000.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxEmbeddedPE limit set to 41943040 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxHTMLNormalize limit set to 41943040 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxHTMLNoTags limit set to 8388608 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxScriptNormalize limit set to 20971520 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxZipTypeRcg limit set to 1048576 bytes.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxPartitions limit set to 50.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxIconsPE limit set to 100.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: MaxRecHWP3 limit set to 16.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: PCREMatchLimit limit set to 100000.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: PCRERecMatchLimit limit set to 2000.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Limits: PCREMaxFileSize limit set to 104857600.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Archive support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> AlertExceedsMax heuristic detection disabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Heuristic alerts enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Portable Executable support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> ELF support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Mail files support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> OLE2 support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> PDF support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> SWF support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> HTML support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> XMLDOCS support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> HWP3 support enabled.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Self checking every 600 seconds.
Thu Jun 15 15:47:53 2023 -> Set stacksize to 1048576
socket found, clamd started.
Thu Jun 15 16:26:07 2023 -> SelfCheck: Database status OK.
```

but when the image is deployed into cloud run, I can' get passed the `Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying`

```
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (35/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:11.899 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (36/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:12.398 EDT
WARNING: Download failed (28) WARNING: Message: Timeout was reached
2023-06-18 19:22:12.498 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (37/1800) ...WARNING: Download failed (28) WARNING: Message: Timeout was reached
2023-06-18 19:22:14.099 EDT
WARNING: downloadPatch: Can't download daily-26902.cdiff from https://database.clamav.net/daily-26902.cdiff
2023-06-18 19:22:14.198 EDT
WARNING: downloadPatch: Can't download daily-26902.cdiff from https://database.clamav.net/daily-26902.cdiff
2023-06-18 18:26:55.898 EDT
2023-06-18 19:22:16.100 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (38/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:17.698 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (39/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:20.098 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (40/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:24.598 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (41/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:27.899 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (42/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:31.799 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (43/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:34.098 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (44/1800) ...
2023-06-18 19:22:36.998 EDT
Socket for clamd not found yet, retrying (45/1800) ...
.
.
.
```

And it goes on like that... I have tried using clamav:latest, clamav:0.104 and clamav:1.1.0. My Docker version is `24.0.2, build cb74dfc1`

My cloud run is deployed with

```
gcloud run deploy "$SERVICE_NAME" \
    --service-account="$SERVICE_ACCOUNT" \
    --region="$CLOUDSDK_RUN_REGION" \
    --platform="managed" \
    --cpu="1" \
    --memory="4Gi" \
    --image="$CONTAINER_FQ_NAME" \
    --min-instances="1" \
    --max-instances="3" \
    --env-vars-file="env.yaml" \
    --update-secrets=ENV="$SECRET_ID:$SECRET_VERSION" \
    --ingress="internal-and-cloud-load-balancing" \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --port="80"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a firewall rule you need to allow for clamav on port 3310? That solved the issue for me on AWS. I had to include an inbound rule for ClamAV on port 3310 to create a socket file.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).